# Overload by return type and arguments

Tags: c++

Is valid to have

```
int func();
float func(int x);
```

I know isn't possible overloading without templates by return type only, but this is valid correct?

Comment: Why don't you try to compile it?

Comment: Compiling to test is the best way to learn bad things. Some comilers accept things that are not in the norm.

Comment: Learn by example is best method.. such things you should try yourself rather asking in forums...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is. The rule for overloading is that the parameters need to be of different type and/or number; when this is satisfied, the return type can be different for the various overloads. Given the actual arguments, the compiler can determine which overload to call.

Only overloading by return type is invalid, because the compiler cannot make a choice based on the return value; suppose you have overloads `int f()` and `float f()`, and you do

```
(void)f();
```

In this situation, there's no telling which `f` you intended to call. (Unless there would be some arbitrary preference for types specified in the Standard, but there isn't, and it would be hard to come up with a sensible one.)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are identified by their signature.
in  C++ function signature include,

1. name
2. argument type
3. no of arguments
4. order of argument

   Return type of function is not consider as a part of signature.
   When a function call is encountered in a program then the compiler will look for functions with that name. If multiple functions have same name(function overloading). then the compiler will check the above signature. if an exact match is not found then compiler will do some conversions and check for a match. Still not found a match it will show an error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct. A function is defined by

- the namespace
- the name of the function
- the types of arguments

But, the return type is not taken into account.

See this example :

```
int f(); // correct
double f(int x); // correct
void f(double y); // correct, the type is different
char f(int z); // Not correct, same signature than the 2nd function
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got a few answer stating that it is possible, but a different question is whether it is desirable, and at this point I would advice against it in your case as it puts a burden on the user: they need to figure out what overload is picked to know what the function returns.

Note that this is not a statement that in general it is not desirable, there are many cases where having different return types for different functions make sense, for example `sqrt` taking a `float` will return a `float`, and if the input is a `double` it will produce a `double`, but it is natural from the syntax and the call what the return type is.

In the artificial example you provided that is not the case, or at least it is not obvious, so I'd recommend not to overload but produce different named functions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is fine as you have different arguments for two overloads.Just for your information why compiler can't deduce from only return types which overload to call.

There's a concept called name mangling. Compiler mangles name of each function as per it's ease to call that appropriately.So if a function is,

```
int foo (int x );
```

mangled name would be something in line with foo_int. In this return type is not                  taken into account. So if I have two overloads like

```
int foo (int x );
int foo (char x);
```

mangled names would be something

```
foo_int
foo_char
```

respectively. But if you only choose return type for your overload resolution then it will fail as return type is not taken into account in name mangling.

Comment: The way name mangling is done is a consequence of the language's rules, not their cause. Were overloading on return type allowed, name mangling rules would be different.